# Unexpected Top-Level Exception in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am currently developing an **Android** application in Android Studio. I have imported two modules to the app. The below list shows the structure of the project and the modules I have in the app:

1. **Project Gradle (youtubeapplication)**
2. **Module #1 Gradle (YT SDK String Library)**
3. **App Gradle (app)**
4. **Module #2 Gradle (vIMEOSDKStringLibrary)**

When i try to run the app, I got the following message gradle build, which obviously shows an "Unexpected Top-Level" Exception:

> Output:
>         UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>         com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define LA$1;
>             at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
>             at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
>             at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
>             at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
>             at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
>             at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
>             at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

I have read about that exception. And and it's caused by repeated versions of libraries, i have tried to check the gradle files of the project but couldn't be able to fix it. I'll list the gradle files one by one:

1) **Project Gradle (youtubeapplication)**

```html
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

2) **Module #1 Gradle (YT SDK String Library)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobilecore.jar')
    compile files('libs/vimeo_m_1_0_0_1.jar')
}
```

3) **App Gradle (app)**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.me.thats.youtubeappliction"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+'

    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':YT SDK String Library')
    compile project(':vIMEOSDKStringLibrary')

}
```

4) **Module #2 Gradle (vIMEOSDKStringLibrary)**

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/mobilecore.jar')
    compile files('libs/vimeo_m_1_0_0_1.jar')
}
```

=======================

Edited:

I have just run the Gradle command ":app:androidDependencies" to get the dependencies tree of the project. Could someone please tell me if there is something to do regarding to the output of Gradle command ":app:androidDependencies"

```
    10:52:36 PM: Executing external task ':app:androidDependencies'...
:app:androidDependencies
debug
+--- LOCAL: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.1.1.jar
+--- com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.1.1.jar
+--- youtubeappliction:YT SDK String Library:unspecified
|    \--- LOCAL: ytsdk_4_0_M.jar
\--- youtubeappliction:vIMEOSDKStringLibrary:unspecified
     +--- LOCAL: jsoup-1.7.3.jar
     +--- LOCAL: mobilecore.jar
     \--- LOCAL: vimeo_m_1_0_0_1.jar

debugTest
No dependencies

release
+--- LOCAL: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|         \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.1.1.jar
+--- com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0
|    \--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.2
|         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1
|              \--- LOCAL: internal_impl-22.1.1.jar
+--- youtubeappliction:YT SDK String Library:unspecified
|    \--- LOCAL: ytsdk_4_0_M.jar
\--- youtubeappliction:vIMEOSDKStringLibrary:unspecified
     +--- LOCAL: jsoup-1.7.3.jar
     +--- LOCAL: mobilecore.jar
     \--- LOCAL: vimeo_m_1_0_0_1.jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 3.448 secs
10:52:40 PM: External task execution finished ':app:androidDependencies'.
```

**Note**: This problem occurs when i import Module #2. When i remove it everything complies very well.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As for me, in your dependencies you have same library of different version.
1) Run Gradle     `:app:dependencies`     to see dependencies tree of your project and each of modules
2) Check dependencies list and find duplicating libraries, check their versions
3) If you found some library of different version, update dependency to ensure that you have same version of library anywhere across project.

I just found that you have following build configuration in your Module 2
`compileSdkVersion 20
 buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"`

try to change it to Module 1 configuration:

`compileSdkVersion 22
 buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"`

Comment: I have just run the Gradle command line ":app:dependencies" and i have edited the original post and included the output of that command. Could you please tell me where is the error that caused that exception. And how to fix it?

Comment: @Androider did you execute :app:dependencies on the top level of your project? I see no dependency tree for underlying projects (YouTube + Vimeo SDKs)

Comment: I have edited the original post. I run a Gradle command line called ":app:androidDependencies" and not "":app:dependencies" is that OK? and i run it on the root which is "youtubeapplication". Tell me if this what i should get? Thanks

Comment: I have changed it to Module 1 configuration, and the same problem still exist, a "Top-Level Exception" was thrown. I guess it's something with the libraries in one the modules. Do you have any other suggestions that might solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Reomve recent android studio plugins and install them again this works in most situation

Comment: The project compiles well as i told in the post. However when i try to import another module i got that exception. I know it's because of repeated libraries in the project, anyway i have included all the build.gradle files in addition to the output of ":app:dependencies" Gradle command which list the dependencies of the project. Please tell me what is the problem and how to fix it. Thanks.